# Avoid two same values in consecutive column during sampling the whole DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random, sample

I want to randomize my DataFrame by 'pd.sample' method, but in order to achieve conditional sampling. I need the results satisfy the below condition: no same values of two consecutive rows in certain column.

```
e.g.: A  B
      a  2
      b  3 
      c  3
      d  4
```

I wanna the sample results like

```
e.g.  A  B
      a  2
      c  3
      d  4
      b  3
```

(i.e. rows where B hold same values would not be consecutive)

How can I achieve this? I already have something below, but as a newbie I am not familiar with writing loop sentence:

```
def compareSyllable(data):
    for i in data:
        (data['B'] != data['B'].shift()).any()

while compareSyllable(data) == True: 
        for i in range(data):
            data_final=data.sample(frac=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

### `compare_syllable`

I'd use the values attribute to get a numpy array.  The syntax is cleaner for this comparison.  And IIUC, you don't want any matching values from one row to the next... in any column.  So using `all` on a numpy array automatically checks every value in the array.

### `conditional_sample`

I made this so that you can actually pass whatever parameters you want to `pd.DataFrame.sample` via the `pd.DataFrame.pipe`.  I've also parameterized the predicate on which the conditional sampling depends.  Meaning, you can create other condition functions to pass to suit other purposes.

### `pd.DataFrame.pipe`

`pipe` is a DataFrame method that whose first argument is a callable.  `pipe` passes to that callable as its first argument, the same DataFrame that called `pipe`.  The rest of the arguments are passed to the callable.

```
def compare_syllable(data):
    v = data.values
    return (v[:-1] != v[1:]).all()

def conditional_sample(df, predicate, *args, **kwargs):
    d = df.sample(*args, **kwargs)
    while not predicate(d):
        d = df.sample(*args, **kwargs)
    return d

df.pipe(conditional_sample, compare_syllable, frac=1)

   A  B
2  c  3
0  a  2
1  b  3
3  d  4
```

---

I'll also point out that `pipe` was a choice of mine and we could have also called this via a more normal way like this:

```
conditional_sample(
    df=df,
    predicate=compare_syllable,
    frac=1
)

   A  B
2  c  3
0  a  2
3  d  4
1  b  3
```

---

## Demo

To further demonstrate that we could have passed other parameters, I'll forgo the `frac=1` argument and pass `3` instead which will be the number of rows to sample

```
df.pipe(conditional_sample, compare_syllable, 3)
```

A  B

```
1  b  3
0  a  2
3  d  4
```

Which also satisfies the condition.

---

A version that includes infinite loop handling

```
from itertools import count, islice

def compare_syllable(data):
    v = data.values
    return (v[:-1] != v[1:]).all()

def conditional_sample(df, predicate, limit=None, **kwargs):
    """default limit of None is infinite limit"""
    d = df.sample(**kwargs)
    for i in islice(count(), limit):
        if predicate(d):
            return d
            break
        else:
            d = df.sample(**kwargs)

df.pipe(conditional_sample, compare_syllable, limit=10, frac=1)

   A  B
2  c  3
3  d  4
1  b  3
0  a  2
```

Comment: Thx a lot for such quick answer. But I'm kind of confused about this sentence you wrote 'I've also parameterized the predicate on which the conditional sampling depends', so what is the parameter named 'predicate'?

Comment: I pass `compare_syllable` as the predicate.  Predicate is the function that defines the condition.  I generalized it so that you can pass another function if you'd like.  So notice that when I call `pipe` the second parameter is `compare_syllable`.  That is will be the predicate.  I'll update my post, hopefully making it clearer.

Comment: @CarrieLin I added an example where I call `conditional_sample` in a way that should make it more obvious what is happening.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. Thanks for your patience. ;)

Comment: excuse me again... if I only want one column values to avoid consecutive values. Could I change the compare_syllable to something like: def compare_syllable(data):
    v = (data['syllable']).values
    return (v[:-1] != v[1:]).all(); I'm kind of lost during debugging...

Comment: @CarrieLin yes you could